# JSX element type 'Query' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Stuck with this typescript error. Trying to use `Query` component from `react-apollo`.

```
JSX element type 'Query<any, { id: number; }>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Query<any, { id: number; }>'.
[ts] JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.
[ts] Property 'query' does not exist on type '{}'
```

Versions:

```
typescript: "^2.9.2",
apollo-boost: "^0.1.16",
react-apollo: "^2.1.11",
```

Component:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import * as React from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

const ORGANISATION_QUERY = gql`
  query OrganisationQuery($id: Long!) {
    organisation(id: $id) {
      tasksEnabled
  }}`;

export class FeatureCardGraphQlComponent extends React.Component<{}
{}> {
public render() {
 return (
  <Query query={ORGANISATION_QUERY} variables={{ id: 1 }}>
    {({ data }) => {
      return <div>{data}</div>;
    }}
  </Query>
 );
}}
```

Comment: Once I add the missing comma, I'm unable to reproduce the problem.  Something may be wrong with your React typings, but I don't have a great idea of how to troubleshoot it remotely.  Can you publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a comma after the {}

try this:

```
const ORGANISATION_QUERY = gql`
  query OrganisationQuery($id: Long!) {
    organisation(id: $id) {
      tasksEnabled
  }}`;

export class FeatureCardGraphQlComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
public render() {
 return (
  <Query query={ORGANISATION_QUERY} variables={{ id: 1 }}>
    {({ data }) => {
      return <div>{data}</div>;
    }}
  </Query>
 );
}}
```